# Django add every user in foreign key model with default values

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I have created a Django model with a foreign key from user, I want that all created user before be created in that table with a default value:

Models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfiles(models.Model):
    myuser = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    userstatus = models.CharField(default='active', max_length=20)
```

Can you help me that I can migrate this table and be created to all users who are registered before?

Comment: Your question is not clear, as I understood, when a user object is created, you want to create a userProfile object for that user, if this is the case you can use post_save signals

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

[post_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/signals/#post-save)

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_save, sender=UserProfiles)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created is True:
        UserProfiles(instance)
```

I recommend creating this function in your app folder under signals.py
I hope this is what you are looking for

Comment: if the answer helped you please mark it as "best answer"